# undefined index but i can't understand why

Tags: php

Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['error']) && $_POST['error'] != 2 && $_POST['error'] != 1) {
    return true;
} else if (isset($_POST['error']) && $_POST['error'] == 2 || $_POST['error'] == 1) {
    return false;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Please help.
  Thanks.

Comment: can you show more code

Comment: when you do `&&` it will evaluate all conditions until something is false. When you do `||` it will evaluate all conditions until something is true. Since your first conditions evaluated to the false, the 2nd one was invoked but `$_POST['error']` didn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Augwa said:

- The && operator will evaluate all conditions until any one of them is false.
- The || operator will evaluate all conditions until any one of the is true.

A solution:

```
if(isset($_POST['error'])) {

    if($_POST['error'] != 2 && $_POST['error'] !=1) {
        // Do stuff here
        return true;
    }else if($_POST['error'] == 2 || $_POST['error'] == 1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do **&&** it will evaluate all conditions until something is false. When you do **||** it will evaluate all conditions until something is true. Since your first conditions evaluated to the false, the 2nd one was invoked but `$_POST['error']` didn't exist.

You probably want to do this, notice the brackets around your two errors.

```
if(
    isset($_POST['error']) &&
    (
        $_POST['error'] == 2 ||
        $_POST['error'] == 1
    )
)
```

It can also be better re-written as.

```
if(
    isset($_POST['error']) &&
    in_array($_POST['error'], array(1,2))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code as below... always enclose your comparison with || in brackets. because || condition checks up to last piece of code to find out a 'true' value. by re-coding as  ..... && (... || .... ), the executions will return from the point && and will not execute ( .... || ..... ) part

```
if (isset($_POST['error']) && $_POST['error'] != 2 && $_POST['error'] != 1) {
    return true;
} else if (isset($_POST['error']) && ($_POST['error'] == 2 || $_POST['error'] == 1)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return false;
}
```